# Find and Arrow notations not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, arrow-functions

Here is my fiddle [**https://jsfiddle.net/y1s6pttt/**](https://jsfiddle.net/y1s6pttt/) where I have pen down my code

This works fine in Chrome and Mozilla, but not in IE. The problem was with arrow notations. The arrow notations are not working in IE.

This is my part of code where I am getting issue in IE.

```
  months1 = data.reduce((p,c) => ~p.indexOf(c.months) ? p : p.concat(c.months),[]),

  series = data.reduce((p,c) => { var f = p.find(f => f.name == c.project_title);

            !!f ? f.data[months1.indexOf(c.months)] = c.amount*1

            : p.push({name: c.project_title, id:c.project_title,

            data: (new Array(months1.length)).fill(0).map((e,i) => i === months1.indexOf(c.months) ? c.amount*1 : e)});

            return p;

         },[]);
```

I have replaced the code with the code below after executing in [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)

```
  months1 = data.reduce(function (p, c) {

   return ~p.indexOf(c.months) ? p : p.concat(c.months);
    }, []),
    series = data.reduce(function (p, c) {

    var f = p.find(function (f) {

      return f.name == c.project_title;

     });

    !!f ? f.data[months1.indexOf(c.months)] = c.amount * 1 : p.push({ name: c.project_title, id: c.project_title,

    data: new Array(months1.length).fill(0).map(function (e, i) {

    return i === months1.indexOf(c.months) ? c.amount * 1 : e;

   }) });

   return p;
   }, []);
```

Even after replacing with Babel code I am getting the error **Object doesn't support property or method 'find' in jquery**

I need to replace arrow notation with any other function to get the similar output. How to change the code as required.

Comment: what version of ie?

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer does not support [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) nor does it support the [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function Arrays have in any of its versions (these days I'm more surprised when IE *does* support something compared to when it doesn't, though). It seems like you've already dealt with the arrow function problem in your Babel-generated code, so now you just need a polyfill for the `find` function. Here's one from the MDN page I linked to above:

```
// https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.find
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'find', {
    value: function(predicate) {
     // 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
      if (this == null) {
        throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
      }

      var o = Object(this);

      // 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
      var len = o.length >>> 0;

      // 3. If IsCallable(predicate) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
      if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
        throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
      }

      // 4. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
      var thisArg = arguments[1];

      // 5. Let k be 0.
      var k = 0;

      // 6. Repeat, while k < len
      while (k < len) {
        // a. Let Pk be ! ToString(k).
        // b. Let kValue be ? Get(O, Pk).
        // c. Let testResult be ToBoolean(? Call(predicate, T, « kValue, k, O »)).
        // d. If testResult is true, return kValue.
        var kValue = o[k];
        if (predicate.call(thisArg, kValue, k, o)) {
          return kValue;
        }
        // e. Increase k by 1.
        k++;
      }

      // 7. Return undefined.
      return undefined;
    }
  });
}
```

If the version of IE is so old that it doesn't support `Object.defineProperty`, you can create a global `find` function that takes the array in as argument as well as the object to find. You'll need to change all the `this` references to the array object parameter name, though.

Seeing as [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill) worked, you shouldn't need a polyfill for that or [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill), but I'll link to their polyfills here just in case future visitors need them (they fail on IE < 9).